# BlackBerry Push Service error with push initiator application url

Tags: blackberry

i install the blackberry sdk push server and i get app id and the port and i  used the tutorial SamplePushEnabledApp
i registred it with those data

Application ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

PPG Base URL**  http://pushapi.eval.blackberry.com

Push Port:  xxxxxxxx

but in the  push initiator application i use the url https://localhost:8443/sample-push-initiator/ but when i made registration it give me this error :

"Request to register failed. Caused by java.io.IOException: Network operation [Subscribe] failed. Make sure that Content Provider URL is accessible."

can any one help me and tell what should i put in the puch initiator url ?
real ip addres with this port and should have tomcat server in this server ?
thx on advice

Answer (score 0):

Your push initiator URL must be accessible  from internet